# How to limit from 8 to rest of them?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to write something like 
`ng-repeat="s in sportMenu | limitTo:all:7>`
So idea is to skip first seven and get rest of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need angular expressions for that, there is already a pure javascript solution:

```
ng-repeat="s in sportMenu.slice(7)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either set the number specifically `sportMenu.length - 7` or set the limit to the length of `sportMenu`:

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

> The limit will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length

```
ng-repeat="s in sportMenu | limitTo:sportMenu.length:7"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

ng-repeat="s in sportMenu"  ng-if="$index>6"

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-repeat="s in sportMenu" ng-if="$index > 6"
```